# can't rake db:migrate because somethng wrong with postgresql(heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

*現在railsでブログを作っています。
now i wanna make blog by ruby on rails.

*本番環境はherokuでdbはpostgresqlを使用しています。

i use heroku and db is postgresql.

本番用にrake `db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`を行ったのですが、

while rake `db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`,

i got some errors.

> ```
> PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>         Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>         Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```

というエラーがでてmigrationができません。
I cant migrate...

どなたか解決策をお願いします。

how to solve this?

......................................

I just have installed postgresql, and now another error

C:\Sites\workspace\sample_app>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Is postgresql running fine in development?

Comment: do you have postgres installed and running?..

Comment: running in production, I use sqlite3 in development.

Comment: I have just installed.(but i wanna use heroku postgresql , I dont know why I installed it...) , and I got another error.

Comment: C:\Sites\workspace\sample_app>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)